# Unable set user and password on tomcat 8.0.36

Tags: tomcat8

I'm create a lab, for test a tomcat 8.0.36 vulnerability. I'm create my user and pass in tomcat-users.xml and stop and start apache service but its dont work.
Can anyone help me?

Bellow its my tomcat-users.xml, my tomcat its install on /opt/tomcat

```
?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?> 

<tomcat-users>
<role rolename="tomcat"/>
<role rolename="role1"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<role rolename="manager"/>
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager"/>
</tomcat-users>
```